# Folder from which to restore accidentally deleted files

Tags: 12.04, delete, restore, undelete

Ubuntu 12.04. I accidentally deleted some files. I tried restoring them using nautilus, got an error message ("another backup operation in progress" - none that I started).

From memory, isn't there a folder which simply holds deleted files? I think I went to one such folder once and was able to easily copy over what had been deleted.

Could someone please remind me of the path and name where to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you click on the desktop recycle bin?

Otherwise, each user can find the hidden folder here: ~/.local/share/Trash/

Comment: That's the one! Many thanks. Unfortunately, it contained only what I already had seen in the trash folder using the gui. I removed a bunch of files with rm; so it's not possible to restore those? @user265433

Comment: @gnometorule Often after a rm it is gone. You might be able to recover, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: Thanks, I'll have a look! Fortunately, all but one file are also on github, so I can just restore my project from there too.